# ASP.Net MVC5 – "Resource Cannot be found" error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

newbie here. I get the error `The resource cannot be found.` when requesting url */event/details/3*.
I use a MVVM.

My schema is simple. I have "Event", "Person" and "PersonInEvent" tables. "PersonInEvent" is a junction table for the two others (holds the foreign keys).

I am trying to display in the "Details" view the event's data with its id (*/event/details/3*). The event's id is passed to the "Details" controller action, which instantiates my ViewModel that hold an event object. I set this event to be the one with the id that I receive when the viewmodel is created.

According to my controller (see below) I get the error because `vm.Event == null`. But I can't find a way to solve this issue. I have the feeling that it is a basic programming problem, such as how my "Event" property in my viewmodel is created. But still I cannot figure out the solution. Thanks in advance.

My controller's Details action:

```
[HttpPost] // this was the problem
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        var vm = new EventDetailsViewModel(id);

        if (vm.Event == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound(); // I get the error because of this imo
        }

        return View("Details", vm);
    }
```

My view model:

```
public class EventDetailsViewModel
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db = new ApplicationDbContext();

        private readonly int _eventIdVm;
        private Event _event;

        public EventDetailsViewModel(int id)
        {
            _eventIdVm = id;
            _event.EventId = id;
        }

        public Event Event
        {
            get
            {
                return _event = _db.Event.Find(_eventIdVm);
            }

            set { _event = value; }
        }

        public List<Person> Persons
        {
            get
            {
                if (!_db.PersonInEvent.Any(pe => pe.EventId == _eventIdVm))
                {
                    return Enumerable.Empty<Person>().ToList();
                }
                var personsOfEvent = _db.PersonInEvent.Where(pe => pe.EventId == _eventIdVm)
                    .Select(pe => pe.Person)
                    .ToList();
                return personsOfEvent;
            }
        }
    }
```

My view just in case:

```
@model BillSplittingWebApp.ViewModels.EventDetailsViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2>Details</h2>

<div>
    <h4>Event</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Event.EventName)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Event.EventName)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Event.EvenTimeBegin)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Event.EvenTimeBegin)
        </dd>

    </dl>
</div>
```

**EDIT:** Problem was the attribute `[HttpPost]` that I forgot to remove for the action.

Comment: The `Details` method above only gets called when a Form is posted, because of the attribute [HttpPost]. Do you also have a `Details` method that uses attribute [HttpGet]? If so, please include that code as well in your question.

Comment: @Peter B That was it indeed... I tried to send the id through post method earlier, and I forgot to remove the attributes.

Comment: Side note, this is not MVVM, it's MVC.  That's why it's called aspnet *MVC*.

Answer (score 3):

This is a poor way MVC is a Pattern it's self. ViewModels should not be referencing databases directly. However, the issue is that in your viewModel you have declared a private Event Object. In the constructor you are trying to set the id of this object without first instanciating a new instance.

You can remove this line of code as it's not doing anything useful in the constructor anyway:

```
 _event.EventId = id;
```

Comment: Thanks bilpor. Problem was my _HttpPost_ attribute as Peter told in the comment. The line you mentionned also threw an error that disappeared once I removed it. "_ViewModels should not be referencing databases directly_" so I should populate the view model properties in my controller and build the logic in that controller is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, the point of MVC is in it's name Model-View-Controller. Controllers should be as light as possible and the best way to look at these are as switching mechanisms to pass data down to a service layer and onto a data layer. The viewModels should define the data that the view's need to display. it's fine to have constructors here, but they get assigned from the controller. (look up Seperation of Concern), SOLID Principles and DRY. Always code with these in mind and you will not go far wrong. Also consider 'Defensive' coding. If it can be broken someone will break it.